# Why can not I see the title of navigationitem?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Why can not I see the title of navigationitem? I'm a real novice but my storyboard works like this: Navigation bar -> Tab Bar -> View Controller. In the viewcontroller I can see the tab but not the title of the navigation item.

[image: this is the storyboard]

[image: this is on simulator]

sorry for my English I'm from Argentina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topmost child of the navigation controller is the view controller whose title is shown in the navigation bar. In your project, that child is the tab bar controller. Your tab bar controller has no title, so nothing appears in the navigation bar.

(This is one of many reasons why a tab bar controller inside a navigation controller is bad design. Notice that Apple does *not* list this configuration as one of the intended ways to use a tab bar controller: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW2)

Comment: I put the title in the tab bar controller and now it was shown. I will consider for future projects not to generate that sequence nav controller -> tab bar. Thank you so much